# Android studio , how to align multiple text view and edit texts in linear layout(horizontal)

Tags: java, android-fragments, android-studio, android-edittext, textview

I'm a beginner in android development, my project requires me to build a simple UI app using two fragments (home and field). The home will show the starup page with 5 buttons. when we click on these buttons, it will then call field fragment and show fields like:

conductivity:----,height:---- 
and etc to fill up, like inserting manual data.

my issue here is , the project requires me to use linearlayout in horizontal alignment for the field frag, when i do that and add edit text and text views, its lined in same line as horizontal, but what i need is it to appear one and the other below it: SOme thing like

conductivity(text view): ___________(editText)
[another line]
height(text view):________(editText)

and so on. SOrry this might be a simple issue but i have been stuck on this for 2 days now. Help me

my code for field fragment.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hp1_textView"
    android:id="@+id/hp1_textView"
    android:textSize="32sp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<LinearLayout        android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/hp1_textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">
    <TextView            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/conductivity"
        android:id="@+id/textView"/>
    <EditText            android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="@string/conductivity_field" />
    <TextView            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="pH:"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />
    <EditText            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="0.-14" />

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[THis is how i want it to display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZr4X.jpg)

Comment: please simplify your question. i cant get it .

Comment: so i have a field fragment, which is in linear layout(horizontal), but i need the textviews and edittexts to be lined up as the image attached, how can i do that??

Comment: you better put a screen capture

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this xml in your code as it is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:weightSum="2">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Conductivity (uS):  "
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="745.2" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:weightSum="2">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="pH:  "
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="7.1" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:weightSum="2">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Moisture(%):  "
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="0-100" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:weightSum="2">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textVie4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Dissolved oxygen(ppm):  "
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="0-100" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Save Log Entry" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Show Log Entry" />


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:weightSum="3">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Previouse" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Next" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Home" />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope its solve your problem.....

Answer (score 1):

Try below with `android:weightSum` and **LinearLayout** with `android:orientation`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hp1_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="hp1"
        android:textSize="32sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="12">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="conductivity"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="conductivity_field" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="pH:"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="0.-14" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Moisture(%):"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="0-100" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Disolved Oxygen(ppm)"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="0-100" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button11"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Save log entry"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button12"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="Show log entries"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="conductivity"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="conductivity_field" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="conductivity_field" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thanx it worked :D its just that my project wanted me to use horizontal allign blahh blaah !!! anyways thank you this helped

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding of your scenario is correct, to display them one below the other as in the `image` you have supplied, the `orientation` of the `linearLayout` must be set to `vertical`. If you use `orientation` `horizontal` the drawing of `widgets` will falls to the next line, only after it has drawn `widgets` completely all the way up to the `width` of your phone( and then it jumped to the next line) .So the `LinearLayout` should be changed to `vertical orientation`

```
<LinearLayout       
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/hp1_textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">
```

Comment: For more refer these sites [1](http://android4beginners.com/2013/07/lesson-2-1-how-to-build-android-app-with-simple-but-powerful-linearlayout-plus-layout-orientation-as-well-as-size-and-weight-of-elements/) and [2](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html)